# ASSIGN a value to an attribute of a widget within a frame

Tags: assign, openedge, progress-4gl

While learning Progress 4GL, I stumbled upon following piece of code, assigning a value to an attribute of a widget within a frame:

```
ASSIGN Rep-Editor:READ-ONLY IN FRAME Dialog1 = YES
       Rep-Editor:SENSITIVE IN FRAME Dialog1 = YES.
```

As you can guess:
`Dialog1` is the name of the frame.
`Rep-Editor` is the name of the widget, placed within the frame.

This looks very confusing to me: it's like saying that the value of the frame equals "YES", I expect the assigned variable and value to be next to each other, something like:

```
ASSIGN Dialog1.Rep-Editor:READ-ONLY = YES, /* or: */
ASSIGN Dialog1->Rep-Editor:READ-ONLY = YES
```

This, obviously, is not the right syntax. Is there a Progress syntax, similar to this one, that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ... that’s almost 40 year old ABL syntax ...

You could wrap everything inside a

```
DO WITH FRAME Dialog1:
  ASSIGN Rep-Editor:READ-ONLY = YES
         Rep-Editor:SENSITIVE = YES.
END.
```

block.